Scala <- for loop flatMap annotation - defining type
I am using for loop in scala for flatMap annotation like this
for {
  conf <- configRepository.getConf(key)
  info <- customRepository.getInfo(id)
  _ <- DBIO.from(getAdditionalInfo(info))
} yield ()

On the line _ <- DBIO.from(getAdditionalInfo(info)) I am getting this info
[error]  found   : Seq[Either[CustomService.Error,Unit]] => slick.dbio.DBIOAction[Unit,slick.dbio.NoStream,Nothing]
[error]  required: Seq[Either[CustomService.Error,Unit]] => slick.dbio.DBIOAction[Unit,slick.dbio.NoStream,E2]

Is there any way, how to define return type for <- (flatMap) ? Or I will need to rewrite for loop to flatMap and define type like this flatMap[Seq[Either[CustomService.Error, Unit], NoStream, Effect.All]]

With that info is a bit hard to understand what's exactly the issue. Based on the error message I can assume you are using slick. What's the signature of the methods from configRepository? The for yield in scala it's just syntax sugar for flatMap, map and with filter. You can check scala for yield examples. Is that piece of code inside a function? Maybe the value returned by the for yield doesn't match with the return type of the function. Please edit your post and add more con text

for isn't really a loop in Scala, although in many cases it might be quite similar to one. But when you have several x <- y in the same for, then the y in each of them has to be the same outermost "wrapper" type: only collections/only options/only futures/only DB operations etc. Rewriting to flatMap will not help much if that is not the case, although might make it slightly more explicit where the mismatch is.

Based on the error message, type parameter E is not inferred
https://scala-slick.org/doc/stable/api/slick/dbio/DBIOAction.html
sealed trait DBIOAction[+R, +S <: NoStream, -E <: Effect]


how to define return type for <- (flatMap) ?

You can try to add type ascriptions:
for {
  a <- fa
  b <- fb
  c <- (fc : Type_of_fc)
} yield d

or
for {
  a <- fa
  b <- fb
  (c: Type_of_c) <- fc
} yield d

Either this will help type inference or you will have a new compile error and see that you try to substitute a value of some type where a different type is expected.
